# Where to place files to be used as command line arguments in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, file, command-line

I am creating a project in C using Visual Studio and I need it to read a file and do an analysis on the text in that file. I have to pass the file to the command line, but I do not know where to place this file in order for it to be read. Here's the main method to help explain how this will be working:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

FILE * cmdFile;
char * nxtCmd = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * STR_LEN);

//Ensure memory allocation for nxtCmd succeeds
if (nxtCmd == NULL){
    puts("Memory failed to allocate for nxtCmd.");
    exit(1);
}

// check if argc is 2
if(argc == MAX_ARGS){}
else{
    puts("Innapropriate number of arguments passed to the program.");
    exit(1);
}

// check that argv[1] can be opened
if ((cmdFile = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL){
    puts("Can't open the command file.");
    exit(1);
}

else{
    puts("Command file has opened successfully.");
}

// if both above are true:
//    start reading from the cmdfile
while ((nxtCmd = nextLine(cmdFile)) != NULL){
    nxtCmd = nextLine(cmdFile);
    printf("next line: %s", nxtCmd);
}
}
```

Any help or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anywhere will do, just pass it to the program on the command line:

```
myprog.exe \path\to\file.txt
```

Comment: As mux said, suppose the file is C:\My Folder\File.txt, just pass it as mypprog.exe "c:\My Folder\File.txt"